# Can I run a C program containing setuid() without sudo?

Tags: c, setuid

I am trying to execute a C program from multiple users and trying to login as other user within the program to access a file. But I am getting error

> setuid: Operation not permitted

Can I do something such I needn't to use sudo every time? Like, giving full access to the program to use setuid as it wants without calling sudo everytime?

Comment: This question belongs probably to SuperUser. You solve it by setting the SUID file attribute, like `sudo chmod u+s your_program`

Comment: You can also consider making a root-owned server spanning the program on demand under the correct user (or just ssh into that user for that matter).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on the system, and your privileges in it, you might be able to change the owner or group of the program to one that has privileges to setuid, and then set the *setuid* or *setgid* mode on the executable via `chmod`:

```
chgrp wheel my-awesome-program
chmod g+s my-awesome-program
```

or

```
chown superduperuser my-awesome-program
chmod u+s my-awesome-program
```

Please be aware that by doing so, you create a potential security hole. If someone can overwrite your program, they could use it to gain privileges. Do this with caution.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to use `setuid` on the program's executable itself using [`chmod`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod):

```
sudo chmod u+s executable
```